# Why is my database table not loading using in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, database, model-view-controller

I am using a dbinitializer to try and seed data to a couple tables on my database. Everything seems to be ok except my `Enrolls` table doesn't want to populate. The `Enrolls` table holds all the `List<>` values of my `Students` and `Courses`. From that `Enroll` table I should be able to see which student is enrolled in which course. I am following a Microsoft docs tutorial but seem to hit a snag.

The thing is when I include the `Enrolls` property while creating an object in the initializer the entire database does not seed. However when I comment it out all tables except `Enroll` seed. I poked around a bit before I came here. Just hoping for a little guidance with some fresh pair of eyes as to where I should check/debug.

Truly hope I asked in a way that is understandable.

This is the `DbInitializer`:

```
public static class DbInitializer
{
    public static void Initialize(StudentRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.Database.EnsureCreated();

        // Look for any students.
        if (context.Students.Any() )
        {
            return;   // DB has been seeded
        }

        var students = new Student[]
        {
            new Student
            {
                FirstName="A",
                LastName="B",
                Address = new Address
                            {
                              HouseNumber = "19", 
                              Street="A ", 
                              City="C", 
                              Country = "T", 
                              Email="s", 
                              PhoneNumber = "6"
                               },
           **//    Enrollments = new List<Enroll> { new Enroll { CourseID = 2, ID=1 } }**
               },
            },
        };

        foreach (Student s in students)
        {
            context.Students.Add(s);
        }

        context.SaveChanges();
      
        var course = new Course[]
                     {
        new Course{CourseName = "Introduction to Computer Hardware",CourseCode = "ITEC120", NoOfCredits =  3, Category = Category.COMPULSORY},
        new Course{ CourseName = "Introduction to Operating Systems", CourseCode= "ITEC122", NoOfCredits = 3, Category = Category.COMPULSORY },
        new Course{ CourseName = "Programming 1",CourseCode = "ITEC133", NoOfCredits = 3, Category = Category.COMPULSORY},
        new Course{CourseName = "Human and Computer Interface Design", CourseCode = "ITEC229", NoOfCredits = 3, Category = Category.COMPULSORY},
        new Course{CourseName = "Webpage Design", CourseCode = "ITEC240", NoOfCredits = 3, Category = Category.COMPULSORY},
        new Course{CourseName = "Computer Networks Architecture and Protocol", 
    };

        foreach (Course c in course)
        {
            context.Course.Add(c);
        }

        context.SaveChanges();


        var teacher = new Advisor[]
        {
            new Advisor{
                            FirstName="Teacher",
                            LastName="One",
                            Address = new Address{ HouseNumber = "123456",
                                                    Street="Teacher Street",
                                                    City="College City",
                                                    Country = "Trinidad",
                                                    Email="teacher@gmail.com",
                                                    PhoneNumber = "5648965"
                                                  },
                            Department="Department1",
                            Specialization=Category.ISD
                     },
        };

        foreach (Advisor t in teacher)
        {
            context.Advisor.Add(t);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();

        var enroll = new Enroll[]
      {
            new Enroll{CourseID = 2,  ID =2  },
      };

        foreach (Enroll e in enroll)
        {
            context.Enroll.Add(e);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
 }
```

My model classes:

```
public class Enroll
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
 
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }

    public Course Course { get; set; }
   // public  DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }
}

public class Student : Person
{
    //  public List<Course> Attends { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }
    public List<Enroll> Enrollments { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public string CourseCode { get; set; }
   
    public double NoOfCredits { get; set; }

    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public List<Enroll> Enrollments { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }

    public string FullName
    { 
        get 
        {
            return FirstName + " " + LastName;
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out my issues. It was a mixture of ...

Editing the `OnModelCreating` function in the context

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Enroll>()
        .HasOne(s => s.Student)
        .WithMany(en => en.Enrollments)
        .HasForeignKey(fk => fk.ID);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Enroll>()
        .HasOne(s => s.Course)
        .WithMany(en => en.Enrollments)
        .HasForeignKey(fk => fk.CourseID);
}
```

....and making my collection properties virtual:

```
public class Student : Person
{
    public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }
    public  virtual List<Enroll> Enrollments { get; set; }
}

public class Enroll
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public string CourseCode { get; set; }
   
    public double NoOfCredits { get; set; }

    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Enroll> Enrollments { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks guys